# How do I force WFP Toolkit to use the Aero theme?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I thought there would be an easy answer for this, but after an hour of searching I'm no closer to an answer.  I just want the WPF Toolkit to use the Aero theme, independently of whether the user has that theme enabled.  In my App.xaml I have included the Aero theme, as well as included the library in the project.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
     ...
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

This works great for all the normal controls, (Buttons, TextBoxes, etc) but for the SplitButton from the WPF Toolkit Extended it still uses whatever theme the user currently has enabled.  I can style a control but I confess a little bit of ignorance about how themes work.  How do I tell the SplitButton to use the Aero theme?  Browsing the source code for WPF Toolkit I see there are Aero theme folders, and I've tried including those in the App.xaml but it didn't seem to make a spot of difference.  I've tried:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;component/Themes/Aero/Brushes_NormalColor.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;component/Themes/Aero/Buttons_NormalColor.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;component/SplitButton/Themes/Aero/Brushes_NormalColor.xaml"/>
```

None of that worked.  I just want my application to have a consistent look across versions of Windows XP, Vista, and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need to reference `PresentationFramework.Aero` in your project.
Right click your Project `Add` -> `Reference...`

If I'm not mistaken do the same in your `Toolbar` view.

Comment: Like I said, I have the Aero theme added as a reference and it is working for all normal buttons, etc.  It is the SplitButton from WPFToolkit that is still using whatever theme the user has their desktop set to.

Comment: I looked at the Template and some colors are set with the system, like you said. [Go to the source](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/SplitButton/Themes/) and change the colors to whatever you want. Attention where the colors are set as `...System.`